# Detecting screen density programmatically, pre-Honeycomb

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout that works in certain phones, but in the Samsung Galaxy Ace doesn't work properly. I need to create a new layout for this phone (and similar) but I can't do it programmatically with [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) or [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) since this phone uses Android 2.2 and those solutions are for Android 3.2 and upwards. How can I create a new layout for this phone below Android 3.2?

Comment: Most of the techniques outlined in the second link work from Android 1.5 onwards. Certainly, resource set suffixes like `-hdpi` work from Android 1.5 onwards.

Comment: @CommonsWare The problem is that I tried with 'layout-mdpi' for the Galaxy Ace and it never got the layout there, it simply used the default one -and Galaxy Ace is 320×480.

Comment: You normally do not use densities with layouts, but rather screen sizes. The Galaxy Ace should be a normal screen size device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end, was creating a folder called 'layout-sw320dp' which the Galaxy Nexus will take -while the Galaxy Ace will use the layout in the normal 'layout' folder- and I did the pertinent modifications for each phone/layout.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(
            displayMetrics);

    switch (displayMetrics.densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH: 
     ...
    }
```