# Android app layout folder name for Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a layout folder for Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562 phone which display size is 480 x 800 pixels, 4.0 inches (~233 ppi pixel density)

I found the following tutorial for helping layout creation
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Strange thing is there is not any sample for ~233 ppi pixel density

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nexus S is a 4.0 inches 480x800 device and it's a `normal` screen size device with a `hdpi` density. So I guess your device has the same setting, but if you would like to know exactly these two values, you can get them programmatically with a sample app as explained here:

[How to detect the android screen size programmatically ( the 4 standard sizes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612048/how-to-detect-the-android-screen-size-programmatically-the-4-standard-sizes)

[Detecting screen density programmatically, pre-Honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933701/detecting-screen-density-programmatically-pre-honeycomb)

Anyway, since your device should have the most common size, you can start developing your application putting the layout in the "standard" `layout` folder: please do not provide a layout file for any possible screen size. The link you have posted is anyway a good starting point to read in order to understand how to manage layouts on Android for different devices.

Of course, if you need to, you could think about having a different layout for the landscape orientation (`layout-land` folder) or for large or greater devices, like Nexus 7 o Nexus 10, using folder `layout-sw600dp`. The smallest-width qualifier (`sw`) is available only on Android 3.2 and above.

This is my suggestion and if you have a more specific issue with a layout please come here and someone will help you.